# div sliding effect does not work with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I created this question before but in another way and got no answers. So today I wrote some simple code to share my problem in a clear way.

1. I used `jQuery` to call an image slideshow function.
2. The AJAX function in `show.php` will call `get.php` and print the results in a DIV.

My problem is that sliding (prev - next) inside the DIV supplied by `get.php` does not work in `show.php`. But if I call `get.php` directly in my browser, then it works.

I am confused, I guess I have an error in my div when calling AJAX.

**My Files**

**show.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>test </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="newscript.js"></script>
        <link href="themes/2/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="themes/2/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include("samiloxide.php");
            $sql=mysql_query(" select * from  section ");

            while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo "<li><a  onclick='loadpage($r[id])' >$r[section]</a></li>" ;
            }
        ?>
        <div id="pageContent"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**newscript.js**

```
var section;
function loadpage(section){ 
    var section = section.toString();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "get.php",
      dataType: "script",
       data: ({section : section}),
     success: function(html){
            $("#pageContent").empty();
            $("#pageContent").append(html);
        }
    });
}
```

**get.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #gallery-wrap{margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; width: 732px; position: relative;}
    #gallery{position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;}
    #gallery li{float: left; margin: 0 20px 15px 0;}
    #gallery li a img{border: 4px solid #40331b; height: 175px; width: 160px;}
    #gallery-controls{margin: 0 auto; width: 732px;}
    #gallery-prev{float: left;}
    #gallery-next{float: right;}
    -->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        // Gallery
        if(jQuery("#gallery").length){
            // Declare variables
            var totalImages = jQuery("#gallery > li").length, 
            imageWidth = jQuery("#gallery > li:first").outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round(jQuery("#gallery-wrap").width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth);

            jQuery("#gallery").width(totalWidth);

            jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function(){
                if(jQuery("#gallery").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")){
                    jQuery("#gallery").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
                }
                return false;
            });

            jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function(){
                if(jQuery("#gallery").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")){
                    jQuery("#gallery").animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
    -->
</script>

           <?php
            include("samiloxide.php");
//if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$section = (int)$_POST['section'];

$sql=mysql_query(" select * from images  where section='$section'");

echo "
<div id='gallery-wrap'>
    <ul id='gallery'>
    ";


while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

      echo " <li><a href='$rr[image]'><img src='$rr[image]' alt='' /></a></li>";
           }
           echo "

    </ul>
</div>
<div id='gallery-controls'>
    <a href='#' id='gallery-prev'><img src='images/prev.png' alt='' />next</a>
    <a href='#' id='gallery-next'><img src='images/next.png' alt='' />last</a>
</div>
           ";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, and I am unable to provide a quick fix to your code that you could just copy, paste and verify.

In `get.php`, you load a document with a gallery, and you *make* it a working gallery from `$(document).ready()`.

But in `show.php`, when you load the `get.php` file, `$(document).ready()` is not called. The `$(document).ready()` of `show.php` was already called long before, and your document is now in the `interactive` state. So when you load the layout, you do not automaticallly execute the code that makes that layout work.

You have to move the `$(document).ready()` code in your `get.php` into `show.php`, and then bind it to the AJAX call completion. Or unbind the code in `get.php`: just call it from the end of the HTML without wrapping it in `$(document).ready()`.

**This is not guaranteed in all browsers all the time**, though, because while `$(document).ready()` is called properly on document being ready, in `show.php` what you do is you ask to load a HTML file.

And the HTML gets loaded, and so `onLoad` gets fired. You can't expect different.

*Then* that HTML asks to load other assets (such as images), but the browser did not know this. It has already fired the `onLoad` and so you already executed the gallery setup code. If the layout requires the images' SRC to be *already loaded* in order to style properly, then it will not always work. It might work the second time because the images are in the browser cache. It may work on fast connections and not on slow connections; it may work with small images, quickly loaded, and not with larger images. All these behaviours indicate that *images being already loaded is necessary*.

Again, a quick and dirty fix is to fire the setup after a suitable delay (but what is suitable? You can't know). Another possibility, if all the images are of known sizes, is to supply those sizes in HTML or CSS. After all, the layout usually requires images being loaded *so that they occupy space on the page*, but for that, you don't need images to be actually *displayable*. They might be empty spaces (maybe styled with a background).

A third possibility, more complicated but guaranteed to work in all browsers, is to save the image SRC's into another kind of tag (e.g. DIVs with a class of *imageloading*, by default hidden), and after the load() success to analyze these tags and convert them to IMGs attaching an `onload` to them. When all those onloads have fired, you know that it's OK to launch the gallery setup. While longer to describe (and code), this last method is actually *much faster* than the naive "quick fix: wait a bit and fire setup" one.